# Detecting overflow on floats

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

How would I be able to detect overflow on these floats?

Where you would see a difference whether it is set to visible or hidden.

```
overflow: visible;
overflow: hidden;
```

Don't all floats contain overflow?

Why am I not able to detect it?

On this code I’m not able to detect where the overflow is.

Is there a way where I would be able to visually see where it is?

https://jsfiddle.net/8ad6yhek/

```
.container {
  width: 936px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #0059dd;
  background: #000000;
}

.container-top {
  position: relative;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 0 0 45px 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url("") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;   
}

.container-left-video {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.container-right-video {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen you fiddle and the first thing is when you use float property you need to clear them otherwise it will overflow. To clear float you can use following code:.

```
.clearfix::after {
   display: block;
   content: "";
    clear: both;
}
```

And you need to add this clearfix class on parent of float containers, in your case container-top will have another class i.e clearfix.

Comment: Did I do this right? https://jsfiddle.net/d72rtw9z/2/ Can you fix it if I didn't.

Comment: Am I supposed to see a visual difference with it added to it?

Comment: When your div is overflowing then it will add unnecessary scroll to your page. If you want to see the exact difference between overflow hidden and visible the set the fix pixel width 500px to the text block and then start your dev tool and check the page on 320 or less than 500 screen size. You will see the horizontal scroll on the page as width of our text block is greater than the screen size.